# Java- Debo preguntar que planeta deseo ver y enseñar dos ArrayList diferentes?

Tags: java, poo, arraylist, herencia, polimorfismo

debo realizar un programa en el que después de ingresar los datos en dos arraylist uno para satélites y otro para planetas,en un tercer método pregunte que planeta deseo ver y debo coger los datos de los dos arrayList anteriormente creados con diferentes datos y mostrar por pantalla el planeta que deseo ver.

```
public static void mostrarAstro() {
    //solicitar el nombre de un Astro y muestre su información
    String respuesta;
    System.out.println("Que planeta deseas ver?");
    respuesta = lector.nextLine();

    if(respuesta == planetaPertenece) {

    }

    System.out.println("\n**Astros**");
    if(listadoSatelites.size() > 0 ) {
        for(Satelites ls: listadoSatelites) {   
            System.out.println("\n"+ls.toString());
        }   
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("---------------");
    }

    if(listadoPlanetas.size() > 0 ) {
        for(Planetas lp: listadoPlanetas) { 
            System.out.println("\n"+lp.toString());
        }   
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("---------------");
    }
    }
```

Mi idea era algo si como preguntar que planeta deseo y luego mostrar los datos de ese planeta y su/s satelite/s.

Pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer que encuentre el planeta adecuado si tengo muchos planetas y como hacer que el planeta se enlace con el satelite o los satelites de ese planeta.

estas son las variables de planeta que se guardan en el primer arrayList:

```
double radioEcuatorial;
double rotacionEje;
double masa;
double tempMedia;
boolean gravedad;
double distanciaSol;
double orbitaSol;
double satelites;
String respuesta;
```

y estas son las variables que se guardan en satelites:

```
    double radioEcuatorial;
    double rotacionEje;
    double masa;
    double tempMedia;
    boolean gravedad;
    double distanciaPlaneta;
    double orbitaPlanetaria;
    String planetaPertenece;
    String respuesta;
```

no se muy bien como hacer esto con arrayList ni si hay alguna forma?(he de añadir que estoy usando herencia y polimorfismo para los objetos de planeta y satelite que heredan de Astros siendo este una clase abstracta) Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sea `Herencia o polimorfirmo` el objeto  creado ya es unico entonces
habria que reccorer primero la lista de planetas luego la lista de satélites usando `Indice` el `nombre` del `planeta`

```
    //solicitar el nombre de un Astro y sea correcto
    String respuesta;
    System.out.println("Que planeta deseas ver?");
    respuesta = lector.nextLine();

    System.out.println("\n**Astros**");
    for(Planeta pl: listaPlanetas){
        // recorreomos la lista de planetas por nombre
        if(pl.nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(respuesta)) {
            System.out.println("\n"+pl.nombre());//nombre del Planeta
            //Puedes Imprimir mas atributos
            //Recorremos Satélites segun al planeta al que pertenece
            for(Satelites ls: listadoSatelites) {
                if(ls.planetaPertenece.equalsIgnoreCase(respuesta)){
                    System.out.println("\n"+ls.nombre());//nombre del Satélite
                    //Puedes Imprimir mas atributos
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu valiosa ayuda! he modificado Astro colocandole nombre para que funcionase correctamente y funciona exactamente como requeria el ejercicio!

Answer (score 0):

Yo voy a poner énfasis en la estructura del sistema, ya que manrrique meneses yaranga te ofreció un buen ejemplo de código.

A la clase Astro le faltó el atributo "nombre", en el código de manrrique está igualado a "planetaPertenece", por cierto.

Bueno, estuve pensando qué sería mejor, vincular el planeta en un atributo de la clase Satélite o agregar un atributo arrayList de satélites a la clase Planeta.

En ambos casos debes crear el arrayList de planetas primero, ya que los satélites los tienes dependientes. Hasta ahí, vamos igual, pero... ¿qué es mejor, preguntar por un planeta y que el sistema lo busque mostrando información de todos sus satélites o que, luego de preguntar por el planeta, el sistema busque satélites si es que están vinculados a lo que buscaste? Por código son más o menos igual de complejos de programar, pero por lógica, mentalmente, si preguntas por planetas sería más lógico buscar planetas.

Yo opto por el ejemplo 2. n_n

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Ororok! muchisimas gracias por el curro del diagrama, la verdad es que sin el diagrama me hubiera costado entender la respuesta de manrrique pero gracias a ti he comprendido perfectamente todo!